# Show that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Show that every bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a convergent subsequence.

Well, I know that in $\mathbb{R}$ it is true that every bounded  sequence $(x_n)$, $\{x_n\}\subset [a,b]$, does have a convergent subsequence: setting $X_n = \{x_n,x_{n+1},\dots\}$ and setting $a_n= \inf X_n$ and $b_n = \sup X_n$, we can show that $a = \lim a_n$ and $b = \lim b_n$.

But how do I extend this result to $\mathbb{R}^n$? By the same process in every coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> By the same process in every coordinate?

Pretty much. Find a subsequence which is convergent in the first coordinate. Then a subsequence *of that subsequence* convergent in the second coordinate. This will still be convergent in the first. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

More or less.

If $\{x_i = (x_{i,1},...x_{i,n})\}$ is a bounded sequence, then the sequences of the $k$ component of the $n$-tuple, i.e. the sequences $\{x_{i,k}\}$ will be bounded sequences in $R$.  Each of those converge.  It's easy then to show that $\lim x_i = (\lim x_{i,1},\lim x_{i,2}....., \lim x_{i,n})=X$.

=======

However for your sanity, I would suggest that you first prove that $d(x,y) = \sqrt{{\sum (x_i-y_i)^2}}$, the euclidean metric, (for $x =(x_1,..., x_n); y=(x_1,....,y_n)$) and $D(x,y) = \sum (|x_i - y_i|)$, the taxi-cab metric, are two metrics that are equivalent.

That is a set $S$ is open with one of the metrics if and only if it is open with the other.  You can prove this by noting for any $x$, any open ball with metric $d$ (which *will* a ball or sphere) will contain and open "ball" with metric $D$ (which will be a cube) and vice versa.

The "taxi-cab" metric $D$ will make your arithmetic, *much* simpler than the euclidean metric $d$.

And the actual arithmetic doesn't matter, of course.

$||X - x_i||_D < \epsilon$ for all $i > N$ is arithmetically *much* easier then the arithmetic to show $||X - xi||_d < \epsilon$ for all $i > M$.  Although they are both intuitively exactly the same.